# How can I input matrix as the figure indicates

Tags: matrices

[image]
Please tell me how to input a matrix as drawn in the figure. Thanks for your help.

Comment: At which point do you have a problem? Which is your code until now? You would like to have a solution to a specific issue, not us doing typing work, right? So perhaps show minimal starting code.

Answer (score 2):

I just find a solution for this problem as follows:

```
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 &   &        &        &\alpha_{1k}    &          &    \\
  & 1 &        &        &\alpha_{2k}    &          &    \\
  &   &  \ddots&        & \vdots        &          &    \\
  &   &        & \ddots &\alpha_{k-1,k} &          &    \\
  &   &        &        &1              &          &    \\
  &   &        &        &               &   \ddots &    \\
  &   &        &        &               &          &   1 
\end{pmatrix}
```

Do you have any idea or suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Use `\mathclap` (from `mathtools`) for the `α` column, to improve horizontal spacing w.r.t. diagonal dots?

Comment: I make a try of mathclap command, but the columns get too close. While I get know of mathtools package. Thank you very much.